# Projection of two lines onto third, lengths + 1 angle known, reconstruct other angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have 4 points, A, B, C and D. There's angle $\alpha$ between $CAB$. There's angle $\beta$ between $DAB$.
I project both AC and AB onto AD, giving me AF and AE respectively.

$$
len(AF) = \cos(\beta) * len(AB)
$$

$$
len(AE) = \cos(\beta - \alpha) * len(AC)
$$
(ignore values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in image, distances not to scale)
[image: geometry visualization]

I know:

- $len(AE)$ and $len(AF)$. I call their ratio $r$.
- $\alpha$
- $len(AB)$ and $len(AC)$. **It is $len(AB) = len(AC)$.**

I want to know $\beta$. I divide:

$$
r =
\frac{len(AE)}{len(AF)} =
\frac{\cos(\beta - \alpha)}{\cos(\beta)} =
\frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)} =
\cos(\alpha) + \tan(\beta)\sin(\alpha)
$$

$$
r = \cos(\alpha) + \tan(\beta)\sin(\alpha)
$$

$$
\tan(\beta) = \frac{r - \cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}
$$

So good so far. I put this into C code:

```
double get_beta(double const r, double const alpha)
{
    return atan2(/*denominator*/sin(alpha),
                 /*  nominator*/r - cos(alpha));
}
```

and run it with some numbers...

```
    double const alpha = deg2rad(60);
    double const len_ab_ac = 1;
    double const beta = deg2rad(30);
    printf("BETA given        : %f°\n", rad2deg(beta));
    double const len_af = cos(beta) * len_ab_ac;
    double const len_ae = cos(beta - alpha) * len_ab_ac;
    printf("len(AF) = %f\nlen(AE) = %f\n", len_af, len_ae);
    double const beta_r = get_beta(len_ae / len_af, alpha);
    printf("BETA reconstructed: %f°\n", rad2deg(beta_r));
```

and <s>consistently get $2\cdot\beta$ back?</s> get $90° - \beta$ back?

```
BETA given        : 30.000000°
len(AF) = 0.866025
len(AE) = 0.866025
BETA reconstructed: 60.000000°
```

```
BETA given        : 80.000000°
len(AF) = 0.173648
len(AE) = 0.939693
BETA reconstructed: 10.000000°
```

([Link to code](https://ideone.com/cuJTLj))

**Can someone help me spot my error? What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: help with adding tags greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to flip the arguments in your call to atan2 (nominator, denominator)

Comment: @Vasili oh my; thank's a lot! So my math is correct but I'm just unable to properly read documentation ^^

Comment: @Daniel_Jour: Yes, your math is correct. Atan2 takes $(y, x)$ as the parameters because we have axis $x$ as the starting point for measuring angles but this does not mean we need to switch opposite side and the adjacent side when we call it